# Python UDP-Receive buffer being overwritten

Tags: python, c, string, udp, null-terminated

I have a client(written in Python) and a server(writted in C)

Here is part of my code for python udp client:

```
    for x in range(noResults):
     fName, addr = sock.recvfrom(1000)
     print "Name:", fName
     resultList[x].name=fName.strip('\x00')
     fSize, addr = sock.recvfrom(1000)
     print "Size:", fSize
     resultList[x].size=fSize.strip('\x00')
     fPort, addr = sock.recvfrom(1000)
     print "Port:", fPort
     resultList[x].port=fPort.strip('\x00')
     fIP, addr = sock.recvfrom(1000)
     print "IP:", fIP
     resultList[x].ip=fIP.strip('\x00')
     sys.stdout.flush()
     print "IP:",resultList[x].ip
     i=i+1
```

while the output it produces after communicating with server(written in C) is:

Name: travel Prague.mp4
Size: 1936l Prague.mp4
Port: 5008l Prague.mp4
IP: 127.0.0.1gue.mp4
IP: 127.0.0.1gue.mp4

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: whats expected output?
Can you post whole code (and details for server ?)

Comment: @smushi Expected output for this loop is no overwriting  as in Size,Port,IP

Comment: I would argue that your server is the problem, not the client. If in doubt use tcpdump/wireshark to have a look at the transferred traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I finally changed my server to make a new char string for sending each of name,size,ip,port and send that string via UDP and that solved the problem
Thanks ALL!!